# Disadvantages for using complex meshes for bone controls

Tags: rigging, bones

While going through some tutorials on the basics of rigging in Blender, I kept noticing that the circles I was using as the custom shapes were extremely small and thin. I tried adding a more complex mesh as the custom shape, and it looks like it works correctly. (The below shape is a little exaggerated in size but more of what I was thinking.)

[image]

I was wondering if there are any disadvantages for having a more complex mesh as the custom shape of a bone? e.g. any performance issues or other issues that would be good to keep in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any disadvantage or issue, except for the obvious fact that if a character has a very complex rig, with hundreds of controls, if the shapes aren't little and thin you could get your view quite obstructed.

Comment: And, eventually, viewport performance, although it's hard to imagine that being a realistic concern.